# Object #<Object> has no method 'scrollIntoView'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error. I was under the impression it was a regular javascript function.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".linesresults input[type=submit]").click(function () {
            console.log('here');
            //$('.lineslistwrap').scrollTop($('.lineslistwrap').scrollTop() + $(this).parent().position().top);
            $(this).parent().scrollIntoView();
        });
    });
```

Comment: *"I was under the impression it was a regular javascript function"* That it is, which is why it doesn't work when you call it on a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) is a method on Dom element, `parent()` returns jquery object, so try.

```
$(this).parent()[0].scrollIntoView();
```